# Two-sided printing and collate option

Tags: printing, brother, duplex-printing

Since I have a printer that can printed two-sided I have that option enabled by default to save on paper. Works nicely on my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. What I rarely need (and thus often get wrong) is to print several copies of a document. It turns out that regardless of which options I choose the result is unsatisfactory.

Just to be clear: I am talking about the options below in the standard print dialog.
[image]

- So as soon as I increase the number of copies, the system suggests to print stacks of page 1, then stacks of page 2 and so on. My printer prints the first two pages onto the first sheet of paper and so on, making the whole batch unusable to be distributed into several copies.
- Well, let's turn on collate mode. Clever, now one document is printed in full (let's say all three pages), then the next copy is printed (again all three pages). And my printer, knowing it just printed three pages (and there is still one side of the current sheet left) starts printing page 1 of the next document on the back of the last page of the previous document, making again the whole batch unusable.

Regardless of whether I use Collate or not multiple copies come out unusable when the document has an odd number of pages. This is sad, and it strikes me almost every time I print several copies.

Is there something that I can reconfigure so Ubuntu warns me or behaves better?

For completness: The driver reported by Gnome desktop is 'Brother MFC-J5720DW CUPS', despite the fact that the latest available Brother drivers are installed.

[image]

```
root@silver:~# dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii  brscan-skey                                    0.3.1-2                                    amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                        0.4.11-1                                   amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  mfcj5720dwcupswrapper:i386                     3.0.1-1                                    i386         Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  mfcj5720dwlpr:i386                             3.0.1-1                                    i386         Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                         6-3                                        amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                          1.6-2build1                                amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
root@silver:~# 

root@silver:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
root@silver:~#
```

The printer is accessed via LAN. I have tried to install the latest drivers just when writing this. And figured out I still had the latest drivers already installed - there was no change. Yet in the GUI, when choosing the driver only those with CUPS in their name are offered.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the printer driver. Are you using Brother's proprietary driver, or a generic or CUPS driver?

Comment: It is the 'Brother MFC-J5720DW CUPS' - I added it to the question.

Comment: Is this printer connected by USB, Ethernet, or WiFi? Have you tried installing the driver from [Brother's Support website](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj5720dw_us_eu_as)? Use the 64bit version, not the 32bit ones (those have the suffix i386).  I don't have this printer, so I can't test.

Comment: Added answers to your questions.

Comment: I don't have a solution. You can try the other similarly named drivers from the GUI and see if that makes any difference. I hope someone with better knowledge of the CUPS (and printing in general) will be able to help.